# Inter-word spacing issue with long code tags

Tags: fonts, spacing, sphinx

I'm having an issue with the [Sphinx Documentation Generator](http://sphinx-doc.org/), you may be asking what this has to do with LaTeX. Well, we were hoping to use it for our specification documentation which needs to be generated as a PDF. Sphinx generates PDF output by first converting `reStructuredText` to LaTeX, then LaTeX to PDF.

In our documentation there exists some(okay, a lot) of very long class/interface/etc names such as

```
some.really.long.class.path.that.causes.our.spacing.to.be.atrocious
```

Often, these are referenced mid paragraph (and sometimes many in one paragraph) and can cause issues like pictured below:

[image]

And here is a sample of the LaTeX that is generated by sphinx that was used to create the above screenshot of the issue:

```
% Generated by Sphinx.
\def\sphinxdocclass{report}
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,english]{sphinxmanual}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{\nobreakspace}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[Bjarne]{fncychap}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{sphinx}
\usepackage{multirow}


\title{spacingexample Documentation}
\date{April 01, 2013}
\release{1}
\author{me}
\newcommand{\sphinxlogo}{}
\renewcommand{\releasename}{Release}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\def\PYG@reset{\let\PYG@it=\relax \let\PYG@bf=\relax%
    \let\PYG@ul=\relax \let\PYG@tc=\relax%
    \let\PYG@bc=\relax \let\PYG@ff=\relax}
\def\PYG@tok#1{\csname PYG@tok@#1\endcsname}
\def\PYG@toks#1+{\ifx\relax#1\empty\else%
    \PYG@tok{#1}\expandafter\PYG@toks\fi}
\def\PYG@do#1{\PYG@bc{\PYG@tc{\PYG@ul{%
    \PYG@it{\PYG@bf{\PYG@ff{#1}}}}}}}
\def\PYG#1#2{\PYG@reset\PYG@toks#1+\relax+\PYG@do{#2}}

\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@gd\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.63,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@gu\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.50,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@gt\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.25,0.82}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@gs\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@gr\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@cm\endcsname{\let\PYG@it=\textit\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.56}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@vg\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.38,0.84}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@m\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.50,0.31}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@mh\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.50,0.31}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@cs\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.56}{##1}}\def\PYG@bc##1{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\colorbox[rgb]{1.00,0.94,0.94}{\strut ##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@ge\endcsname{\let\PYG@it=\textit}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@vc\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.38,0.84}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@il\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.50,0.31}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@go\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.19,0.19,0.19}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@cp\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@gi\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.63,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@gh\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@ni\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.84,0.33,0.22}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@nl\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.13,0.44}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@nn\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.05,0.52,0.71}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@no\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.68,0.84}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@na\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@nb\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@nc\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.05,0.52,0.71}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@nd\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.33,0.33,0.33}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@ne\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@nf\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.02,0.16,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@si\endcsname{\let\PYG@it=\textit\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.44,0.63,0.82}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@s2\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@vi\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.38,0.84}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@nt\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.02,0.16,0.45}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@nv\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.38,0.84}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@s1\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@gp\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.78,0.36,0.04}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@sh\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@ow\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@sx\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.78,0.36,0.04}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@bp\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@c1\endcsname{\let\PYG@it=\textit\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.56}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@kc\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@c\endcsname{\let\PYG@it=\textit\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.56}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@mf\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.50,0.31}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@err\endcsname{\def\PYG@bc##1{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fcolorbox[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{1,1,1}{\strut ##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@kd\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@ss\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.32,0.47,0.09}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@sr\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.14,0.33,0.53}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@mo\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.50,0.31}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@mi\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.50,0.31}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@kn\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@o\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@kr\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@s\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@kp\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@w\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.73,0.73}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@kt\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.13,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@sc\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@sb\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@k\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@se\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@sd\endcsname{\let\PYG@it=\textit\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{##1}}}

\def\PYGZbs{\char`\\}
\def\PYGZus{\char`\_}
\def\PYGZob{\char`\{}
\def\PYGZcb{\char`\}}
\def\PYGZca{\char`\^}
\def\PYGZam{\char`\&}
\def\PYGZlt{\char`\<}
\def\PYGZgt{\char`\>}
\def\PYGZsh{\char`\#}
\def\PYGZpc{\char`\%}
\def\PYGZdl{\char`\$}
\def\PYGZti{\char`\~}
% for compatibility with earlier versions
\def\PYGZat{@}
\def\PYGZlb{[}
\def\PYGZrb{]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\phantomsection\label{index::doc}


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tristique, leo in dictum fermentum, lorem sapien rhoncus tortor, 
in fringilla sem magna in velit. Pellentesque bibendum ultricies ligula at bibendum. Proin gravida metus sit amet leo pretium fringilla 
tincidunt orci sollicitudin. Quisque suscipit ligula id massa ultricies eu ultricies lacus imperdiet. Aenean sagittis pharetra neque, 
sit amet aliquet turpis varius ut. Aliquam sed mauris sed risus volutpat bibendum. Praesent id luctus sapien. Class aptent taciti sociosqu 
ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut id orci risus. Curabitur vel rhoncus sapien. Aliquam sollicitudin semper dictum.
 In magna orci, tristique a suscipit ut, fringilla eget dolor. Pellentesque vel neque elit. Mauris in ipsum nibh.
 \code{super.long.class.name.that.we.are.talking.about.that.ruins.our.interword.spacing} Nunc nec mauris elit, sit amet ullamcorper augue. 
 Sed ornare est vel nibh venenatis eu faucibus lorem mattis. Nam lorem nulla, aliquam a convallis vel, lacinia sit amet lorem. Donec vulputate 
 neque in enim aliquam quis ullamcorper nunc consequat. Nunc at ipsum accumsan metus vehicula porta. another. \code{super.long.class.name.that.we.are.talking.about.} 
 Vivamus blandit  \code{more.really.long.class.stuff.} orci ac felis aliquam pharetra sollicitudin felis tincidunt.
 Pellentesque molestie varius dui vitae varius. Sed mauris dui, tristique in blandit tincidunt, iaculis sit amet augue. Curabitur ut tortor sapien,
 a tristique ligula. Etiam porta auctor purus, pretium posuere dolor rutrum ut. Phasellus velit nisl, gravida id volutpat at, porta at orci.
 Etiam dapibus augue sit amet ligula tristique accumsan. Vestibulum nibh elit, pharetra in aliquam ut, auctor id felis. Curabitur posuere euismod orci nec consectetur. 
 Curabitur vulputate, sem eu auctor scelerisque, neque metus aliquet neque, ultrices hendrerit lacus tellus et metus.

Contents:


\chapter{Indices and tables}
\label{index:welcome-to-spacingexample-s-documentation}\label{index:indices-and-tables}\begin{itemize}
\item {} 
\emph{genindex}

\item {} 
\emph{modindex}

\item {} 
\emph{search}

\end{itemize}



\renewcommand{\indexname}{Index}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Now the reason I'm asking on this StackExchange instead of one related to `reStructuredText` is because I'm hoping there is some simple LaTeX solution. Sphinx supplies it's user with a LaTeX preamble variable that allows me to inject LaTeX into the beginning of the intermediate `.tex` file that is used to generate the PDF.

So, does anyone have some sort of solution to my issue? I've seen suggestions where you can give LaTeX "hints" on where it is acceptable to insert hyphens into these really long code tags but there is no built in way for me to get Sphinx to be able to pass through that type of syntax that I know of.

What I need is the class paths to be the teletype/monospaced font style, but have them look better than the default behavior in regards to the spacing between words. Is there some way to redefine the code tags to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I didn't have the sphinx files so used `report` class and ignored the errors but copying the idea of the `url` package you can use math mode and then allow breaking on `.` (or other characters)

```
\def\code#1{$%
\medmuskip0mu \mathcode`\.="213A 
\mathtt{\xdef\tmp{\the\fam}}\fam\tmp#1$}
```

in chat egreg suggested this improved version but I don't think it will address the pythong error that you mention in comments (I have no idea about that)

```
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\code}[1]{$
  \medmuskip=0mu
  \mathcode`\.="2\hexnumber@{\tt@mathgroup\space}2E % period
  \mathcode`\-="2\hexnumber@{\tt@mathgroup\space}2D % hyphen
  \mathgroup\tt@mathgroup#1$}

\sbox0{$\mathtt{\xdef\tt@mathgroup{\the\fam}}$}
\makeatother
```

It appears form comments that the monospace font used in text is not the same as used in math in the sphinx setup so this locally makes sure the text font is used

```
\def\code#1{\texttt{%
\medmuskip0mu
\mathcode`\.="202E
\mathcode`\-="202D
$\fam0 \textfont0\font
#1$}}
```

defines `\code` to use `tt` font on math mode with `.` set as a binary operator with the medium spacing normally applied set to 0 (You can make this a small stretch space to allow line breaking such as `0mu plus 2mu` if you don't mind space appearing around the `.`.

Comment: This is causing a build error when trying to add it to my preamble variables, Exception occurred:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Sphinx-1.2b1dev_20130401-py2.7.egg/sphinx/writers/latex.py", line 284, in astext
    self.generate_indices() +
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xde in position 414: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @JohnLotacs ah well you probably need to keep that definition on the latex side of things, I don't know this system at all but why does adding a latex definition affect what's passed to python? and  where did byte 0xde  come from?

Comment: I think my problem was I had to escape every backslash. However, it isn't building for me, I get ! LaTeX Error: Command \code already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual. I inspected the intermediate .tex file and ergreg's solution was inserted perfectly after the \usepackage definitions.

Comment: Your solution compiles and fixes spacing, but the font styling is a little too subtle. The original seems to have a thinner font, I'm unfamiliar with latex, can you tweak it a bit?

Comment: @JohnLotacs @egreg and I were using the standard classes where \code isn't defined so `\newcommand` you need to redefifine the existing command from the sphinx setup so use `\renewcommand`. If you could show the orignal code definition we could probably see what font it is using and use the same one

Comment: I believe this is the definition
``% Some custom font markup commands.
%
\newcommand{\strong}[1]{{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\bfcode}[1]{\code{\bfseries#1}}
\newcommand{\email}[1]{\textsf{#1}}``

Here is the whole sphinx.sty http://pastebin.com/3RwXxzti

Comment: @JohnLotacs so code there is just using the standard tt font so it should be the same (the redefinition uses math mode so the fonts could be different but it's unlikely) if you add \showoutput (to a small document:-) and compare the log files you will see if it is a different font from the log file

Comment: http://www.macfreek.nl/memory/LaTeX_Bold_Typewriter_Font

I believe what you have given me is "bold typewriter" and I need "normal typewriter".

Comment: @JohnLotacs Not in the standard classes, (in fact the standard font setup doesn't have typewriter in two weights) Perhaps someone who has sphinx can step in and say what font definitions they are using. what does `\texttt{\showthe\font}` produce in the log and terminal, by default it says `> \OT1/cmtt/m/n/10` (computer modern typewriter) but I suspect you are seeing something different

Comment: Sphinx doesn't allow me to inject latex after ``\begin``, so I can't use ``\texttt{\showthe\font}``

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\texttt{\showthe\font}}` in the preamble then:-)

Comment: ``\T1/pcr/m/n/10``

Comment: @JohnLotacs side remark three years later: you can inject latex via ``..raw:: latex`` directive if needed for debugging.